# How to replace the missing data from AMELIA results

Tags: multiple-imputation

I have run a AMELIA imputation for a data set including missing data. I need to replace the missing point by the result of      amelia(). But it content 5 group of imputed values. How can i choose the best one to replace the missing values (to plot a graph of data set after imputing)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I suspect the chain length may be an indicator of quality (the shorter the better), but I'm mostly guessing.